# Hubspot jquery show another div

Tags: jquery, content-management-system, show

I'd like to show another div by calling it in through the jquery .show function. The jquery will be at the top of a content html/javascript module. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#IngeniContentBlock_1328862").show();
});
// ]]></script>
```

This doesn't seem to work. Is there a certain way you have to write this? I saw on another post you could call the div through:

```
($('#'+id).show();)
```

I tried that but didn't work either.

Here's the link: http://12pointssolutions.web12.hubspot.com/hospital-services-0

```
What I want to happen is: 
When you click menu item (Meet the Expert) loads that specific content module
(IngeniContentBlock_1328958) and show content module from "Hospital Services"
(IngeniContentBlock_1328862) in the background.
```

I can't add styles or an id, just overwrite with a custom.css.
 Any ideas? Thanks.

Here's the structure of where the div is:

```
<div id="dnn_ContentPane" containersrc="h1.ascx">
<h1> </h1>
<div id="dnn__ctl0_ContentPane">
<div id="dnn__ctl0__ctl0_ContentPanel">
<div id="IngeniContentBlock_1328862" class="ISContent Normal">
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#IngeniContentBlock_1328862').load('hospital-services-0.html #IngeniContentBlock_1328862');
});
// ]]></script>
```

All I did was fix the spacing and close your jQuery query string, which you left open, by adding a closing `'`. Also, if you haven't already included the jQuery file, the above won't work.

Comment: It's not showing up. I added it to the module if you want to check it out.

Comment: Then the issue lies elsewhere, and I can't help you unless you give us more information. I'd recommend double-checking to ensure that your div's ID really is `IngeniContentBlock_1328862`, and that it does have content.

Comment: Or did you want to display the div with an ID of `IngeniContentBlock_1328958`? I've updated my answer to do that instead.

Comment: I edited my post to show the div structure above. I want to "show" IngeniContentBlock_1328862 in the backgroound of IngeniContentBlock_1328958

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you're trying to do. Are both divs on the same page or is IngeniContentBlock_1328862 on another HTML page? Because if it is, we'll have to use another technique to load it.

Comment: Yes, IngeniContentBlock_1328862 is on a different html page

Comment: I've edited my answer with a hopefully more effective solution, now that I've learned that the target div is, in fact, on another page.

Comment: It's not showing up. Do you think I need to ref the .js from hubspot? Right now it's: src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm sorry, but I don't think I'll be able to help you any more on this. Good luck! Oh, and for the record, your ref should be fine.